# What's wrong with tasksel ubuntustudio- packages?

Tags: package-management, aptitude, tasksel

Trying to install any of ubuntustudio- (ubuntustudio-audio, ubuntustudio-font-meta, etc.) "tasks" with tasksel always fails, saying "tasksel: aptitude failed (100)" (while other options, like lamp-server, for example, work ok). Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just trying this I get the same problem. There is a [similar but ever so slightly different bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/219653) open, that I suggest you mark as affecting you.

Answer (score 0):

Run `tasksel` with the `--test` option, it will only write on the terminal the command it would run.